# Folder Watch for files as windows service?

Tags: process, windows-services

I have created a watcher console application application to watch specific folder if any file is created there it will copy the file to other directory and delete the file over there. The application works as standalone console. But it is not working if I call the same exe through windows service? Will there be any change in setting I am calling like this in windows service

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FolderWatch"].ToString());
  p.Start();
  p.WaitForExit();
  base.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standalone console app will be running in the context of the currently logged on user (Unless you've used 'Run As').

Check the 'Log On' tab on the properties of the service - Is it running as 'Local Service'? This account has minimum privilages. Create an account which has the minimum required access for your service to carry out the required tasks.